# Java Variable / Object ? Doubly-Linked List Logic

Tags: java, class, variables, object, doubly-linked-list

I am given the following code:

```
public class DLLNode{
    //define variables
    public int info;
    public DLLNode next;
    public DLLNode prev;
}
```

I know from this that every object initialized under DLLNode  name can have an integer variable info:

```
node1.info=(some integer)
```

What I don't understand is what the variables next and prev are??

```
node1.prev=?? 
node1.next=??
```

Can DLLNode be a datatype?? If so, what kind of data is permissible??(I also have a feeling these are declared non-initialized objects which can be later initialized though a method or so...).

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: next and prev are variables that refer to DLLNode objects (or objects of a child type), or to null if not yet assigned, just like any reference variable. Your question almost reads to me as "what is a reference variable?" and for that I suggest that you continue to study Java as it's a key concept that must be well and fully understood to progress. With study you will understand this.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: So, next and prev variables can be used as pointers to already initialized objects of the DLLNode class??

Comment: Absolutely. You could have a chain of DLLNode objects, or link them in a circle. Just understand that at any time, they could be null, and so this should always be tested before using the variables as objects.

Comment: awsome...thnks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see the code is **Doubly-Linked-List**

So it's like for example. you have like this

> First - Second - Third

So you should initial

---

- **First.previous** with null it means before First object there is no
  more previous
- **First.next** with Second

---

- **Second.previous** with First
- **Second.next** with Third

---

- **Third.previous** with Second
- **Third.next** with null it means after Third
  object there is no more next

---

1. When you call `First.next` it should be the `Second object` returned.
2. When you call `Second.next` it should be the `Third object` returned.
3. you can also try `Second.next.previous.info` the return it should be **Second.info**
4. Try also `First.next.previous.next.next.info`

Comment: Bro, you just solved my entire problem!!! Thanks a lot!!..:)

Comment: @user3889963 it's good for you

Answer (score 3):

```
What I don't understand is what the variables next and prev are?
```

They are variable of `DLLNode` type, `next` will point to next `DLLNode` object, while `prev` will point to previous `DLLNode` oject.

```
Can DLLNode be a datatype?? If so, what kind of data is permissible??
```

Yes. It will store a primitive or complex type, depending on what you initialize the list with, e.g.

```
DDList<String> dlist = new DDList <String> ();
```